# changed_when: in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble setting up the `changed_when` condition on a specific task on my playbook.

I used to use  `ignore_errors: true` in the past, using the git module:

```yaml
- name: Checkout in client folder
  ansible.builtin.git:
    repo: "{{ item.value.dev_repo | default('git@*****:***/****.git') }}"
    key_file: /tmp/oci_odoo.rsa
    accept_hostkey: true
    dest: "/opt/odoo/odoo_{{ item.key }}/addons"
    version: "{{ item.value.repo_branch | default('main') }}"
    force: false
  with_dict: "{{ clients }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['main']
  ignore_errors: true
  tags: tag1
```

That code gives me an error everytime I run the playbook since there's actually local modifications in the folder :

```
[11:06:42]   ↳ module : Checkout in client folder  | hostname | FAILED | 1.08s
{
  - msg: One or more items failed
  - results: [ {
    - msg: Local modifications exist in the destination: /opt/odoo/odoo/addons (force=no).
    - changed: False
    - before: 1c9a771969222f8ebbab57bd1e173b821f684a04
    - failed: True
    }
    - ansible_loop_var: item
  } ]
  - changed: False
}
```

I then tried to use conditional to make ansible see a change when the text "Local modifications" is present in the result with

```
  register: result
  changed_when: '"Local modifications" in result.results[msg]'
```

or

```
  register: result
  changed_when: '"Local modifications" in result.results.msg'
```

Since debugging the `result` var gives:

```
{
  - result: {
    - msg: One or more items failed
    - results: [ {
      - msg: Local modifications exist in the destination: /opt/odoo/odoo/addons (force=no).
      - changed: False
      - before: 1c9a771969222f8ebbab57bd1e173b821f684a04
      - failed: True
      - changed_when_result: The conditional check '"Local modifications" in result.results[msg]' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ("Local modifications" in result.results[msg]): 'dict object' has no attribute 'results'
      }
      - ansible_loop_var: item
    } ]
    - skipped: False
    - failed: True
    - changed: False
  }
}
```

And with that you get to see the error:

`he conditional check '"Local modifications" in result.results[msg]' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ("Local modifications" in result.results[msg]): 'dict object' has no attribute 'results'`

How can I make ansible thinks there's change when "Local modifications" is returned by the git module ?

Thanks,

EDIT: dict in use :

```
clients:
  client1:
    odoo_version: "15"
    odoo_subnet: "22"
    port_ending_number: "02"
    odoo_passwd: "azertyuiop"
    domain: doe
    dev_repo: git@git.git
```

Comment: Please take note that you are iterating over a list of clients (`with_dict: "{{ clients }}"`) producing a result list (`{
  - result: {
    - msg: One or more items failed
    - results: [ {}
      }
      - ansible_loop_var: item
    } ] ...`). Therefore you need to consider if you like to check if something has changed in example for 1 out of all clients, a few from the list of clients, or a specific one. So what means "local modifactions" in respect to a list of clients?

Comment: @U880D The loop checks out a git repo in a folder BY client, is that's what you were asking. Adding a new client and replaying the playbook does clone the repo and don't touch the others with the `Local modifications` note. I want that note to pass everytime, leaving "real" errors failing.

Comment: => `changed_when: '"Local modifications" in result.msg'`. See the last paragraph in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition must look like this:

```yaml
  register: result
  changed_when: '"Local modifications" in result.msg'
```

The conditions like `changed_when` and `failed_when` are evaluated for each iteration. During the execution of an iteration the result of each iteration step is exclusively available in the variable of the `register` (in your example `result`).

Only after the end of the loop the results of all itration steps are summarized in a list `results`. The list entries within `results` are therefore those results that were previously available exclusively via the variable defined by `register` during execution.

---

Here is another small example.

The following task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - Hello John.
    - The sun is shining.
    - John and Joe drinking a beer.
  register: result
  changed_when: '"John" in result.msg'
```

Results in this behavior concerning `ok` and `changed`:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=Hello John.) => {
    "msg": "Hello John."
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=The sun is shining.) => {
    "msg": "The sun is shining."
}
changed: [localhost] => (item=John and Joe drinking a beer.) => {
    "msg": "John and Joe drinking a beer."
}
```

This is how the content of the variable *result* looks like after execution:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "Hello John.",
                "msg": "Hello John."
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "The sun is shining.",
                "msg": "The sun is shining."
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "John and Joe drinking a beer.",
                "msg": "John and Joe drinking a beer."
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

---

Basically a `with_dict` works exactly the same as a `with_items`, internally the whole thing is evaluated as a `loop`. A loop can basically only run on objects that can be iterated, so internally the dict is automatically converted to a list of dicts with the [filter `dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists).

Therefore the whole thing works the same if I replace the `with_items` with a `with_dict` like this:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value  }}"
  with_dict:
    sentence1: Hello John.
    sentence2: The sun is shining.
    sentence3: John and Joe drinking a beer.
  changed_when: '"John" in result.msg'
  register: result
```

However, you are trying to apply `changed_when`, but at the same time you have set `ignore_errors: true`. This will not abort on error, but the error will still be registered as such.

The following order of precedence applies:

**failed > changed > ok**

If I include a fail for my example task, you will see that the first iteration step is evaluated as `failed`, although it is also `changed`.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value  }}"
  with_dict:
    sentence1: Hello John.
    sentence2: The sun is shining.
    sentence3: John and Joe drinking a beer.
  changed_when: '"John" in result.msg'
  failed_when: '"Hello" in result.msg'
  ignore_errors: true
  register: result
```

The result looks like this:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item={'key': 'sentence1', 'value': 'Hello John.'}) => {
    "msg": "sentence1: Hello John."
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'sentence2', 'value': 'The sun is shining.'}) => {
    "msg": "sentence2: The sun is shining."
}
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'sentence3', 'value': 'John and Joe drinking a beer.'}) => {
    "msg": "sentence3: John and Joe drinking a beer."
}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "One or more items failed"}
...ignoring
```

This is how the content of the variable *result* looks like after execution:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "One or more items failed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "failed": true,
                "failed_when_result": true,
                "item": {
                    "key": "sentence1",
                    "value": "Hello John."
                },
                "msg": "sentence1: Hello John."
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "item": {
                    "key": "sentence2",
                    "value": "The sun is shining."
                },
                "msg": "sentence2: The sun is shining."
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "item": {
                    "key": "sentence3",
                    "value": "John and Joe drinking a beer."
                },
                "msg": "sentence3: John and Joe drinking a beer."
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

In `result.msg` the string "Local modifications" is contained, however an error is recognized and this predominates. Therefore define either `failed_when: false` or find a meaningful condition for the `failed_when` option in the future.

By `failed_when: false` your task will never evaluate as failed and never switch to ignored, but this way a changed can be evaluated as such.

So try the following:

```yaml
  register: result
  changed_when: '"Local modifications" in result.msg'
  failed_when: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer phanaz, it seems to work fine with `with_items`, but `with_dict` it's not. This time I don't have the `changed_when_result` in the output, but the tasks still appears as a failure to ansible. I registered a variable called `output` and point the `changed_when` to `output.msg`.

Comment: What does your dict `clients` look like? Can you provide an example by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75308705/edit)?

Comment: I added more explanation to my post.